# MVC Core input field validation, custom error message with HTML tags

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I'm using ASP.net MVC Core 2, I have a Required attribute (from DataAnnotations) set with a custom error message.

If the message is plain text it works fine.
Eg:

```
[Required (ErrorMessage = "My custom error message")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

But I wish to display this on an error condition:

```
<span class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> My custom error message
```

putting, the html tag part of the message does not work, it just displays it as text

```
[Required (ErrorMessage = "<span class=\"fas fa-exclamation-triangle\"></span>My custom error message")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Because the `HtmlHelper` methods and TagHelpers encode it. Show how you generating the placeholder to the validation method (you can just style the `<span>` it creates by adding the class name)

Comment: Alternative you can override the `field-validation-error` class that is added to the `<span>` when its invalid.

Comment: if your problem with just styling then you just style the `span` or `div` the put the ModelError inside that element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Thanks for the reply ... I'm not really understanding the suggested solutions

In the view (the .cshtml file) this is what I have, this is what generates the error message:

    <input asp-for="UserName" type="email" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>

Comment: @RxNReza thanks for the reply.  
Do you suggest it like this: 
    <span id="x"> 
        <span class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
       <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger">    </span>
    </span>
but then how do I make sure the 'x' only shows on error?

Comment: if you want two validation message then make two span but remember you will get only the error message that you defined in your `Model` otherwise the default error message.